# How to parse through JSON in python with No Array Name

Tags: python, json

How do I parse through JSON in python with No Array Name?

My web request returns the following below and I want to loop through to print out each incident_key. Any help would be appreciated!

```
print(set_data_OD)
    [
        {
            "fields": {
                "description": "85300361",
                "occurred_at": "2018-06-01T15:24:22.655Z",
                "incident_key": "93568087",
                "details": "The Detailed incident 2",
                "service_key": "22644f5943d",
                "event_type": "trigger"
            },
            "model": "test.incident",
            "pk": 1
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "description": "85019988",
                "occurred_at": "2018-06-01T15:14:23.371Z",
                "incident_key": "93289161",
                "details": "The Detailed incident 2",
                "service_key": "22644f5943d",
                "event_type": "trigger"
            },
            "model": "test.incident",
            "pk": 12
        }
    ]
```

Comment: `for x in set_data_OD: print x['fields']['incident_key']`? This isn't really related to JSON, as you just have an ordinary list; the fact that you may have loaded it from a JSON file isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if set_data_OD is not parsed, you can parse it first. Then just loop over each element of the parsed array:

```
import json

set_data_OD = """[
        {
            "fields": {
                "description": "85300361",
                "occurred_at": "2018-06-01T15:24:22.655Z",
                "incident_key": "93568087",
                "details": "The Detailed incident 2",
                "service_key": "22644f5943d",
                "event_type": "trigger"
            },
            "model": "test.incident",
            "pk": 1
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "description": "85019988",
                "occurred_at": "2018-06-01T15:14:23.371Z",
                "incident_key": "93289161",
                "details": "The Detailed incident 2",
                "service_key": "22644f5943d",
                "event_type": "trigger"
            },
            "model": "test.incident",
            "pk": 12
        }
    ]"""
parsed_data = json.loads(set_data_OD)
for object in parsed_data:
    print object["fields"]["incident_key"]
```